# PDC variable created by MFC CDC cannot read memory

Tags: opencv, mfc, cdc

Thank you for your understanding for using Google Translator.

I want the result of getting the webcam screen into picture control with `MFC`

When you compile, you hear “Tiring” and the result window containing picture control closes after 1~2 seconds

There is nothing wrong with compilation, but an error is found when debugging.

Anyone please help me to solve this problem

--

The contents of the error are as follows

```
pDC 0xcccccccccccccccc {hDC=??? attrib=???} CDC *
CObject {...} CObject
m_hDC <Cannot read memory>
m_hAttribDC <Cannot read memory>
m_bPrinting <Cannot read memory>
```

The contents of the source code are as follows

```
else
{
    if (m_pImage)
    {
        CDC* pDC; // Structure with all the information necessary for output: Device Context
        CRect rect; // Rectangular coordinates

        pDC = m_stDisplay.GetDC(); // Get Windows DC: Save to pDC
        m_stDisplay.GetClientRect(&rect); // Get window size information: Save to rect

        m_vImage.CopyOf(m_pImage); // Copy m_pImage to m_vImage
        m_vImage.DrawToHDC(pDC->m_hDC, rect); // Draw m_vImage according to window size rect in window handler m_hDC

        ReleaseDC (pDC);
    }
    CDialogEx::OnPaint();
}
```

Comment: Not sure on a quick look, but I think you need to release the DC from the *same* window you got it from: try `m_stDisplay.ReleaseDC(pDC);`.

Comment: Where do you find that error? That is a debug view to variables -- in which line did you make that "error"-snapshot (looks liek evth is OK)